# Inner product functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\langle .,.\rangle)$ be an arbitrary inner product space.

(a) Prove that if $y, z ∈ X$ are such that $<x,y> =<x,z>$ for all $x ∈ X$, then $y = z$.

(b) Show that if $(x_n)_n>1 ⊆ X$ is a sequence in $X$ convergent to $x ∈ X$ in the
induced norm and such that $x_n$ is orthogonal to $y ∈ X$ for each $n > 1$ then $x$ is orthogonal to $y$.

(c)  Using part (b) or otherwise, show that if $M$ is a subset of $X$, then
$M^⊥ = \{z ∈ X : ∀x ∈ M, \langle z, x\rangle = 0\}$ is a closed linear subspace of $X$ (a linear subspace and a closed subset).

Can someone help me with this problem? I have no idea how to start. Thanks.

Comment: Part (a) is missing some details. Please review your post to make sure all of the proper information is contained therein.

Comment: Consider $\langle y-z,y-z\rangle$ for the first one, expand it using the linearity of the inner product. What is it equal to? What does that tell you about $y-z$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

a) Let $x= y-z$. If $\langle y-z,y \rangle=\langle y-z,z \rangle$, then $\langle y-z,  y-z\rangle = 0 \iff  ||y-z||^2 = 0 \iff y = z$.

b) Let $\{x_n\}\subset X$ such that $x_n \to x \in X$ and $x_n \perp y$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. That is, $\langle x_n, y \rangle =0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. In this case:

$$
0 = \langle x_n, y \rangle = \dfrac{1}{4}[||x_n+y||^2 -||x_n-y||^2] \to \dfrac{1}{4}[||x+y||^2 -||x-y||^2] = \langle x, y \rangle \implies \langle x, y \rangle = 0 \implies x \perp y
$$

c) That $M^{\perp}$ is linear space you immediately check. Let $x\in \overline{M^{\perp}}$. Then, $\exists\{x_n\}\subset M^{\perp}$ such that $x_n \to x$. Let $B$ a base of $M$. We have $x_n \perp y, \forall y \in B$. By item (b), $x \perp y, \forall y \in B \implies x \in M^{\perp} \implies M^{\perp} \ \mbox{is closed.}$